# Eclipse Aptana 3 Plugin Jquery Intellisense Incomplete

Tags: jquery, eclipse, intellisense, aptana

I have been trying to get jQuery intellisense working in Eclipse with the Aptana Studio 3 plugin.  The intellisense working but I am not getting all the available methods in the intellisense popup box.

I have an .html file with a script tag.  When I type "$" the intellisense window pops up. No problem.
If I type $('p'). after the period the intellisense window pops up, but methods like ".next" do not show in the intellisense window.  I opened the jquery.1.6.2.sdocml and searched for the "next" method and found it does exist in the file.

Does anyone have any idea why only a few of the references from this file show up and not all the available methods that exist in the file?

Comment: not an answer to you question, but how did you exactly make it to get jQuery intellisense working in Eclipse Aptana 3 plugin? I followed many articles, but still nothing.